# html2pdf in Angular generating blank pages for larger datas

Tags: angular, html2pdf

html2pdf in Angular generating blank pages for larger datas. Printing blank page with this data:

```
    var option = { margin:[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2],
               enableLinks: false,
               pagebreak:{mode:['avoid-all','css','legacy'],avoid:'table'},
               image:{type:'jpeg', quality:0.98},
               html2canvas:{scale:3, logging: true },
               jsPDF:{unit:'in',format:'letter',orientation:'portrait'},
             };
    html2pdf().set(opt).from(this.elementid).toPdf().get('pdf').then(async function(pdf){
    var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    var image='';
    for(var i=1;i<=totalPages;i++){
    pdf.setPage(i);
    pdf.setFontSize(10);
    pdf.text(footer,pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth()/12.9, pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 0.3,pdf.setFontSize(14),pdf.setTextColor(60,81,146));
pdf.text('Page'+i+'/'+totalPages+'',pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth()/2.0,pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight()-0.3,pdf.setFontSize(8),pdf.setTextColor(150));
    }
window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'),'_blank');
})
```

Is there any other way we can print PDF in Angular?

Comment: Pleas delete the code snippets from the comments - they are unreadable there. Use the edit feature to add them to your post if you have not already done so.

Comment: Here is an alternative for you called jsPDF:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59155467/how-to-export-a-angular-page-into-pdf-with-multiple-page

Answer (score 0):

try to use ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdf-viewer',
  template: `<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="'../file.pdf'"/>`,
})
export class PdfViewerComponent {}
```